# How execute two SQL query in the Spring Boot JPA

Tags: sql, sqlite, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a syntax error in my SQL query. 
This is my query :

```
@Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM Category WHERE id=:id \r\n"
            + "DELETE FROM Product_Category WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteCategory(@Param("id") long id);
```

This is my error:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (near ",": syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly achieve this functionality by writing a native query here.
You need to use `CustomRepository` concept provided by spring and create a method `deleteCategory` that fires two queries inside it using entityManager.
Then you can call that method from your service layer.

Lets assume your Repository name is `CategoryRepository`.

Now, first you need to create a custom repository interface:

```
public interface CategoryRepositoryCustom {
    void deleteCategory(Long id);

}
```

Then write its impl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryRepositoryImpl implements CategoryRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Modifying
    public void deleteCategory(Long id) {
        //execute your two queries one by one using entity manager
    }
}
```

Now, your main repository `CategoryRepository` should extend both `JpaRepostory` and
`CategoryRepositoryCustom` and you can call the `deleteCategory` method from service class.
More about custom repositories [here](https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito)